# Change the real time into a given span of time, with jquery, mysql and/or php

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, clock

I'm working on an RPG chat coded in old php-mysql and javascript (at the time there was no jquery), and the playing story is about vampires (not a twilight style, I assure you :P).

And I need to set a time watch visible, that doesn't have the real time, but only a night time, extended throughout all day.

For example, at real time 6 AM, must correspond a in-game time of 20PM, and so on, until a real time 5:59AM, which must correspond to a in-game time of 5AM.

So that through the whole real-life day, the in game time span goes only from 20PM to 5AM, only the night, in short.

Is it possible? It's ok to use php and mysql, or even jquery or javascript (even though I think it would be easier done with the last two).

PHP writing is in the old procedural style, not object oriented, just to specify.

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I would think the algorithm would go something like this:

1. Calculate what percentage of an actual day has passed.
2. Use that to calculate how much time has passed in a virtual day (multiply times 32400 to get the number of seconds, probably).
3. Add that number of seconds to a date object that has been set to 20:00PM on today's date.

Comment: @AndreaRomito _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."_ Give it a try, then come back for help if you get stuck.